# Overwrite Zend_Config and access parents nodes

Tags: zend-framework, config, overwrite

I want to overwrite Zend_Config method __set($name, $value), but I have same problem.

$name - return current key of overwrite config value, eg:

```
$this->config->something->other->more = 'crazy variable'; // $name in __set() will return 'more'
```

Because every node in config is new Zend_Config() class.

So - how from overwritten __set() metod get access to the parents nodes names?

My application:
I must overwrite same config value in controller, but to have controll about the overwritting, and do not allow to overwrite other config variables, I want to specify in same other config variable, an tree-array of overwriting allowed config keys.

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Config is read only unless you have set $allowModifications to true during construction.

From the `Zend_Config_Ini::__constructor()` [docblock](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Config_Ini.html#%5CZend_Config_Ini):-

```
/** The $options parameter may be provided as either a boolean or an array.
 * If provided as a boolean, this sets the $allowModifications option of
 * Zend_Config. If provided as an array, there are three configuration
 * directives that may be set. For example:
 *
 * $options = array(
 *     'allowModifications' => false,
 *     'nestSeparator'      => ':',
 *     'skipExtends'        => false,
 *      );
 */
public function __construct($filename, $section = null, $options = false)
```

This means that you would need to do something like this:-

```
$inifile = APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini';
$section = 'production';
$allowModifications = true;
$config = new Zend_Config_ini($inifile, $section, $allowModifications);
$config->resources->db->params->username = 'test';
var_dump($config->resources->db->params->username);
```

Result

> string 'test' (length=4)

**In response to comment**

In that case you can simply extend Zend_Config_Ini and override the `__construct()` and `__set()` methods like this:-

```
class Application_Model_Config extends Zend_Config_Ini
{
    private $allowed = array();

    public function __construct($filename, $section = null, $options = false) {
        $this->allowed = array(
            'list',
            'of',
            'allowed',
            'variables'
        );
        parent::__construct($filename, $section, $options);
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if(in_array($name, $this->allowed)){
            $this->_allowModifications = true;
            parent::__set($name, $value);
            $this->setReadOnly();
        } else { parent::__set($name, $value);} //will raise exception as expected.
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about it very well, but I dont want to allow modification to whole variables in config, but only for specify variables. So I must overload Zend_Config, and manualy filter which variable i want to overwrite, which not.

Comment: In that case see my addition above

Comment: ah, I see your problem now. The object returned is always a Zend_Config!! My 2nd solution won't work. I'll try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Always there is another way :)

```
$arrSettings = $oConfig->toArray();
$arrSettings['params']['dbname'] = 'new_value';
$oConfig= new Zend_Config($arrSettings);
```